# how to insert a matrix into a vector<vector<char>>

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix

I would like to push a 5x4 matrix
[11110,
11010,
11000,
0000] into a

```
vector<vector<char>> myvec;
```

myvec[0].push_back('1') throws vector subscript out of range error.

Comment: You can only use `[]` for rows that exist already

Comment: What do you mean by "insert"? Do you want just to store this matrix 5x4 in `myvec` or somehow shift the existing data to also store the matrix there?

Comment: I just want to store the matrix 5x4 in myvec

Comment: Repeating your original words is not useful. They were unclear at the start and remain so now!

Comment: You may, if you want, edit your question to clarify exactly what you are trying to do in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a vector of vectors, and you have forgotten to insert a new "row" into the outer vector first.  For example, you might do this:

```
myvec.resize(4); // create 4 rows now
for (auto& row : myvec) {
    row.reserve(5); // make space for 5 columns (makes push_back faster).
}
myvec[0].push_back('1');
```

---

As an aside, a vector of vectors is usually a suboptimal choice for storing a rectangular matrix.  It wastes space, and it doesn't guarantee that the matrix remains rectangular at all (each row could be a different width).  But if you don't care much about performance, or your matrices are small, I suppose it isn't a big deal.

Comment: The `reserve` loop is redundant

Comment: @M.M: What do you mean precisely?

Comment: The code works fine without it, and "makes push_back faster" seems unlikely, you are just changing when the allocation happens but there is still an allocation.  My main point is that OP might have read your answer and thought this was a required step

Comment: @M.M False, most allocations schemes are going to have to repeatedly reallocate. They have no idea how many elements you want and many I know of follow a power of two allocation scheme, which is far from ideal individually inserting 5 elements.

Comment: @M.M: With `reserve()` there is exactly one allocation per row.  Without it, there are `log(columns)` allocations per row, and likely unnecessary copying of data after each allocation.  So yes, the code works without `reserve()`, but many people using C++ do care about performance, and I am one of them.

Comment: A note: it would be possible to avoid the loop using an initializer list or a fill constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You created a empty vector and then tried to access a non-existent element with `[0]`.

One thing you can do is create the vectors at the sizes you require like this:

```
// 4 vector elements (rows) each containing a vector of 5 char elements
std::vector<std::vector<char>> v(4, std::vector<char>(5));
```

Then you don't need to use `push_back()` to add elements, they are ready to use:

```
v[0][0] = '1';
v[0][1] = '1';
v[0][2] = '1';
v[0][3] = '1';
v[0][4] = '0';


v[1][0] = '1';
v[1][1] = '1';
v[1][2] = '0';
v[1][3] = '1';
v[1][4] = '0';

// ... etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create and initialize the vector of vectors in one step:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> myvec{
    {'1','1','1','1','0'}, 
    {'1','1','0','1','0'}, 
    {'1','1','0','0','0'}, 
    {'0','0','0','0','0'}
    };
```